# Linq Contains not working after migrate from vs2010 to vs2012

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I just migrate my project from vs2010 to vs2012 and when I try to execute this method the statement seems to get no data. The same code works fine on vs2010.

```
var result2 = (dc.Table1
    .Where(p => p.Descripcion.Contains(descripcion) && p.Estado == 1)
    .GroupJoin(dc.Table2, 
        p => p.Codigo, 
        a => a.Codigo,
        (p, a) => new { p = p, a = a }
    )
    .SelectMany(
        temp => temp.a.DefaultIfEmpty(), 
        (temp, a) => new Listado() 
        { 
            codigo = temp.p.Codigo, 
            descripcion = temp.p.Descripcion, 
            alias = a.Descripcion, 
            id = a.Id 
        })
    )
    .ToList();
```

Any suggestion to fix the problem is welcome.

Comment: So you get a list with 0 entries?

Comment: It's not going to have anything to do with your version of Visual Studio. Are you still pointing to the same data source as you did before the migration?

Comment: Yes, I was getting 0 entries and it is the same database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by upgrading to EntityFramework6, it seems that EntityFramework5 still has some bugs. I am using the same method and data but now I'm getting the expected data.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had a similar problem when upgrading EntityFramework, as a result I switched to using the .Any() method instead.